# SSAS Calculated Member Conditional Count

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx, condition

I have a table representing Accidents and a column with Accident Severity ranging from 'Slight' to 'Fatal'. I want to create a measure counting Fatal Accidents depending on other columns on the Accidents table and others (Road Type, Weather Conditions etc.)

What would the calculated member for this measure be and would adding it to a Fact Table consisting of Foreign Keys from all those tables be enough to accomplish what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you already have designed

- a **measure** `Total` that counts the accidents
- a **dimension** `Severity` that describes the severity of the accident

you can define a calculated member such as:

```
([Measures].[Total],[Severity].[Severity].&[Fatal])
```

Comment: This is so obvious, except that it is not -- not the first time you run into this. I'd give you +1000 if I could.